# tk: store input from Entry in variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried to search how to save a variable from an input using TK, but I can't find any way to do it.

That's a cleaner version of the code I'm using:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

main=Tk()
main.title("Test")
book = []

class test1:
        def __init__(self):
                self.name = ""
                self.tel = ""

new1 = test1()

def salva(argm):
        argm.name = str(nome.get())
        argm.tel = str(telefono.get())

def nuovo_ordine():
        tutto = Toplevel()
        scheda = ttk.Frame(tutto,padding="10 10 10 10")
        scheda.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        scheda.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        scheda.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        global nome
        global telefono
        global new1
        nome = StringVar()
        telefono = StringVar()
        ttk.Label(scheda,text="Telefono").grid(column=1,row=2)
        ttk.Label(scheda,text="Nome").grid(column=1,row=1)
        tel1 = ttk.Entry(scheda,textvariable=telefono).grid(column=2,row=2)
        nome1 = ttk.Entry(scheda,textvariable=nome).grid(column=2,row=1)
        salva_tasto=Button(scheda,text="Salva",command=salva(new1)).grid(column=1,row=4)
        fine_tasto=Button(scheda,text="Fine",command=tutto.destroy).grid(column=3,row=4)

def stampa(argm2):
        print (argm2.name)
        print (argm2.tel)

dentro = ttk.Frame(main,padding="10 10 10 10")
dentro.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
dentro.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
dentro.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,W,E,S))
nuovo=Button(dentro,text="Aggiungi Ordine", command=nuovo_ordine,     width=16).grid(column=1,row=2)
stampa=Button(dentro,text="Stampa Ordini",command=stampa(new1),    width=16).grid(column=2,row=3)
chiudi=Button(dentro,text="Chiudi",command=main.destroy, width=16).grid(column=3,row=4)
main.mainloop()
```

Problem is, it seems like it's unable to store in the variables the input, while if i try:
    print (telefono.get())
I get the right value...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
salva_tasto=Button(scheda,text="Salva",command=salva(new1)).grid(column=1,row=4)
```

If you specify the arguments of a function in `command`, you have to wrap it in a lambda so it isn't immediately called.

```
salva_tasto=Button(scheda,text="Salva",command= lambda *args: salva(new1)).grid(column=1,row=4)
```

By the way, it's a common mistake to try to assign a widget to a variable, and `grid` or `pack` it on the same line. If you want `salva_tasto` to be a Button and not whatever is returned by `grid`, you should do

```
salva_tasto=Button(scheda,text="Salva",command= lambda *args: salva(new1))
salva_tasto.grid(column=1,row=4)
```

---

Edit: you also have a naming problem. You have a function `stampa`, but you override that name with `stampa=Button(...`. You should change the name of one of these variables to something else.

Comment: first: thanks for the answer! but using lambda doesn't help, i still get blank as a result from print... Moreover, what does *args stand for??

Comment: Did you also wrap `command=stampa(new1)` in a lambda? Every command that uses parentheses needs a lambda. `*args` is an [arbitrary argument list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). I put it in because I couldn't remember how many arguments get passed to a command when it's called, and `*args` guards against any "too many arguments" errors. Trying it out, you could just do plain `lambda:` without `*args` as well.

Comment: Yes I tried, what I get now is a:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
related to the stampa(new1) command

In the meanwhile, I've noticed that without lambda if i define self.tel = "aaa" it gets printed as soon as I start the program..

Comment: I just noticed that myself - see the edit to my post. `stampa` is both the name of a function and a Button.